# Biorthogonal sequence in Hilbert space

Tags: hilbert-spaces

Let $\{x_n\}$ and $\{y_n\}$ is the two biorthogonal sequences in the Hilbert space $H$. It means $<x_i,y_i>=\delta_{ij}$. Prove that the two sequences is linear independence.

My teacher said that is an easy exercise but i'm very thank you for answer me. Sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Suppose $\alpha_1 x_1 + \ldots + \alpha_n x_n = 0$. What happens if you inner product both sides with $y_1$?

Comment: i can see that the element of $\{x_n\}$ is linear independence, but it said that the two sequences is linear independence, so is it right if i take $\alpha_1\{x_n\}+\alpha_2\{y_n\}=0$ and then prove $\alpha_1=\alpha_2=0$?

Comment: No; you're trying to show that each sequence is linearly independent by themselves. So, whatever argument you did for the $\lbrace x_n \rbrace$ terms, do it for $\lbrace y_n \rbrace$. You don't have to show that they're independent of each other. Besides, I'm not even sure what $\alpha_1 \lbrace x_n \rbrace$ refers to!

Comment: okay thank you so much for answer ^^